# React ciclic graph for skill tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

What and how I should create a graph for a skill tree. It's like a tree but a child can have more parents and a parent can have child from a level higher with more than 1. Here is a photo. I'm mostly interested in the arrows between them and I want to make then rounded like a bezier curve or something similar.
[preview of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIUpD.png)

[other example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ttzl.gif)

Comment: It sounds like what you're after is an [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), if I am not mistaken.. You should be able to use something like [react-dag](https://github.com/ajainarayanan/react-dag) for this.. [Demo](http://react-dag-app.surge.sh/) of `react-dag`...

Comment: I would prefer something with customizable or curved edges arrows.

Comment: It looks like you [can customize](https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/toolkit/current/articles/views) the views.. `react-dag` is a wrapper for `jsPlumb` and you can supply your own config.. Otherwise, I'm sure you can edit the look/feel via CSS...